Compose not recomposing all the time when expected
I have a simple composable function, but it is not behaving as I would expect:
@Composable
fun Example() {
    val show = remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }
    if (show.value) {
        Text("Showing")
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(3000)
        show.value = false
    }
}

Expectation: Text is not shown after 3 seconds
Observation: Sometimes text is not shown after 3 seconds, but sometimes it continues to be shown
Can someone please explain why the if statement sometimes seems not to evaluate. It is seemingly random as well which is even more confusing.

Have you made sure that the show.value = false really is executed when you expect it to be executed? You can check by using the debugger or a Log.d statement.

I can't reproduce the issue on Compose 1.7.0-rc01. Please try to update your dependencies. There also might be some other code causing this side effect.

I'm not facing such an issue. After 3 seconds, the text is not visible. The code works perfectly for me in @Preview with Interactive Mode without running the app.
